# Django:How to upload,display,delete images by admin

Tags: python, django

I would like to display some pictures in the front-end, however I  want to upload, delete and update pictures by the admin instead of writing code in front-end. I've finished some codes yet.I don't know how to do next.
My code for the settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static/images/bxslider/')
MEDIA_URL = '/images/bxslider/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
)
```

models:

```
class BxSlider(models.Model):
    status_choice = (
        (0,'online'),
        (1,'offline'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=status_choice,default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    herf = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True)

    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'BxSlider'  
        verbose_name_plural = 'index slider'  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views:

```
def index(request):
    #addr = models.BxSlider.objects.get()  #I don't know how to write this
    return render(request,'index.html',{"addr":addr})
```

index.html:

```
<div class="bxslider">
<div><img src="" style="width:100%;"></div> <!-- I don't know how to write,so I can call pictures from admin -->
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Unrelated, but you should NOT put uploaded contents in your static dir - there are good reasons for statics and medias having distinct settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to upload,delete and update pictures by admin instead of writing code in front end

Answer is here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

> I don't know how to write this

```
def index(request):
    #addr = models.BxSlider.objects.get()  # I don't know how to write this
```

How could *we* know which of the BxSlider records you want ? But if you want say the last modified of the online ones:

```
     addr = models.BxSlider.objects.filter(status=1).order_by("-last_modified").first()
```

All this ORM querying stuff is documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/

> I don't know how to write,so I can call pictures from admin

You don't "call pictures from admin" (this doesn't make sense), you get them from your model. But anyway, here again the answer is [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#filefield):

> The uploaded file’s relative URL can be obtained using the url attribute

So you want, quite simply:

```
<div class="bxslider">
  <img src="{{ addr.img.url }}">
</div>
```

Comment: WOW! Thank you a million times!！ I can learn a lot of things from your answers!!！

Answer (score 0):

> I want to upload,delete and update pictures by admin instead of writing code in front end.

1) You can use default django admin dashboard. You don't have to write code for this. It's just shipped as default with django.

- Access admin dashboard http://localhost:8000/admin/ for development server(Change localhost with your host address if required).
- createsuperuser to access your django admin dashboard

2) Register your model @admin.py, for which you want upload, delete and update pictures.

You can read more about default admin dashboard below link:

https://first-django-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you every one!I've figured out this problem,Here is my answer:

settings:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'medias/bxslider/')
MEDIA_URL = '/medias/'
```

models:

```
class BxSlider(models.Model):
    status_choice = (
        (0,'online'),
        (1,'offline'),
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=status_choice,default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='')
    herf = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,editable=True)
    update_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,null=True)

    class Meta: 
        db_table = 'BxSlider'  
        verbose_name_plural = 'index slider'  

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.name
```

index.html

```
<div class="bxslider">
{% for i in img_addr %}
    <div><a href="{{ i.herf }}"><img src="/medias/{{ i.img }}"  style="width:100%;"></a></div>
{% endfor %}
```